# I’m getting the error down at the terminal, anytime I type npm run dev on the terminal. I have the dependencies already in my package.json

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npm-run

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kshhg.png)

It shows that error and I’ve tried so many times [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJrH4.png)

Comment: please post text, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question asked is poorly written, it is a fairly easy problem to resolve.

Delete the `space` character between `NODE_ENV=` and `development` in your `dev` script.

Because there is a space between these 2, the parser interprets `development` as a program to execute, not a variable.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please mark this question as solved if it solved your issue.